# DEBUG/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: android, debugging, push-notification, socketexception

I am using the deacon library for getting push notifications in my android application. I implemented the demo application, but I am not able to connect to the meteor server in my application from my office connection. However, when I try connecting from home, it works. Seems like something is blocking the connection at my workplace.

When I run the app in debug mode in the office, it gives the error -

```
DEBUG/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

What could the problem be? How can I check/debug this issue? 
I want to know where the problem lies, in the connection or in getting the response?

Comment: It sounds like it could very well be a blocked TCP port at your office.

Answer (score 0):

SNTP is the Network Time Protocol. The emulator tries to fetch the actual time. I think, this has nothing to do with your app.

Taken From: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/117495/javanetsocketexception-address-family-not-supported-by-protocol